# Ruby on Rails, Grape unintialized constant Blog::Grape

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-grape

I have to build an API for an existing web application built using RoR. I read somewhere that it can be achieved using Grape gem. To implement and practice this, I tried doing it with a simple Blog application that I built using [Getting Started with Ruby](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).

This is my `lib/api.rb`:

```
module Blog
class API < Grape::API
    prefix 'api'
    resource 'articles' do
        get do
            Article.all
            end
        get :id do
            Article.find(params[:id])
            end
        end
    end
end
```

This is the `config/routes.rb`

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do


 resources :articles do
    resources :comments
    end

root 'welcome#index'
require 'api'

mount Blog::API => "/"
end
```

I'm stuck in the last second step, where it says to run the command

`rake middleware`

It gives the following error:

> uninitialized constant Blog::Grape. The error is in api.rb

**Questions**:

1) My assumption that with Grape, we can add Restful API to the existing web application is correct? If not what should I use. You can tell in reference to the simple blog web application built using RoR, mentioned in the Getting started guides.

2) How do I resolve the above error?

Comment: You have `gem 'grape', '~> 0.1.5'` in your Gemfile, and ran `bundle install` or `bundle update` after changing that, correct? The error is saying it can't find variable type `Blog::Grape`

Comment: Yes I did that and it successfully installed 3 gems named `rake-jsonp-1.3.1`, `multi_xml-0.5.5` and `grape-0.1.5`

Comment: From the example, it seems you need to have a model called blog already created, as the author said he was using the api to tie into that, but I might be a little mistaken. But if you read the last lines it says rake sound execute `run Journal::Application.routes`

Comment: Blog is the name of my application. Do you have any idea about how to implement API for an already existing app.